# Chef: Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/couchbase/libraries/helper.rb cannot load such file -- chef/rest

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox

I have vagrant : Vagrant 1.7.4, and a devbox cookbook, when I do vagrant up is showing me a compile error :
       Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/couchbase/libraries/helper.rb  cannot load such file -- chef/rest .

With same setup, same cookbook is working for all other machines.

full logs : https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/uploads-eu.hipchat.com/102620/3335846/qsb5ZamnZGZ7Rdf/log.txt

Can some help?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you're using the Chef 13 pre release that went up today. If so, that file is indeed removed and the cookbook needs to be updated. The official Chef 13 release will be on Monday and it will take some time for even a reasonable number of cookbooks to port to it.

Comment: Thank you, Is working now, I have downgrade vagrant to 1.7.4 that use chef 12.